# Como hacer una fullscreen app en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Buen dia, estoy intentando hacer una app fullscreen. y estoy compilando por cable usb en un redmi 11.  pero tengo el siguiente problema, a continuacion mostrare como se ve la pantalla de mi celular cuando aplico las opciones mostradas. lo que quiero es lograr el comportamiento de immersivesticky pero con la pantalla entera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que use es el siguiente:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestBackground extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestBackground({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestBackground> createState() => _TestBackgroundState();
}

class _TestBackgroundState extends State<TestBackground> {
  int _selected = -1;
  var botones = [
    'manual []',
    'manual [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]',
    'manual [SystemUiOverlay.top]',
    'immersiveSticky',
    'immersive',
    'edgeToEdge',
    'leanBack',
    'manual [top,bottom]',
  ];
  Future<void> aux = 
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Color.fromRGBO(64, 115, 64, .5),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text("Screen height: 
            ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.height}"),
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selected = i;
                  });
                  ejecutarAccion(i);
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    color: i == _selected ? Colors.blue : 
                    Colors.red,
                    child: Text(botones[i])),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void ejecutarAccion(int i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual, overlays:[]);
        break;
      case 1:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,overlays:[SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
        break;
      case 2:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,overlays:[SystemUiOverlay.top]);
        break;
      case 3:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
        break;
      case 4:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
        break;
      case 5:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
        break;
      case 6:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
        break;
      case 7:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays:[SystemUiOverlay.top,SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Por lo que pueden ver cuando uso immersive sticky  obtengo el comportamiento deseado, pero me deja una barra negra en la parte donde iba el status bar, y cuando quito los bordes manualmente tambien.
alguien pudo encontrar una solucion?

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto:

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])`

debe ocultar ambas barras, para volverlas a habilitar intenta:

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);`

Comment: no funciona, lo que quiero es  que cuando la aplicacion se este usando este en modo fullscreen, y cuando el usuario deslice su dedo ya sea arriba para ver el status bar, o abajo para ver el navigation bar, ahi recien aparezca y luego de unos segundos desaparezca o desaparezca al hacer tap en el body de nuevo.